# Wifi,Blutooth,Web Cam is not been detected by Ubuntu 12.10 lts

Tags: wireless, drivers, bluetooth, webcam

I am using HP Pavilion 15 -no11tu which has been awarded the status of Enabled for Ubuntu.

When ubuntu was shiped with my hp laptop,Everything worked fine including wifi,webcam and bluthooth.

Some days ago I formatted my System and reinstalled ubuntu 12.04.3 lts which i downloaded for ubuntu website.
But Insted of connecting my system to internet and after doing all update and upgrade ubuntu didnt detected my system wifi,bluetooth and webcam.

HP does not provide driver support for linux.

Please Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the kernel. Just run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Generally drivers are included in the kernel so you need to upgrade the kernel. Try using Ubuntu 13.10. I also had some problems with my laptop even after upgrading the kernel of 12.04 . But 13.04 solved everything . So you should try 13.10 .